# Lubuntu20.04: How to make Alt-Tab cycle through only current workspace's windows and Ctrl-Alt-Tab fo switch through all windows in all workspaces?

Tags: lubuntu

I found some tweaks pertaining to Gnome Shell, but how do I edit these shortcut keys to get the intended behavior on lubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should work with the following definition in `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` (this might be `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` in plain openbox):

```
<keybind key="A-Tab">
  <action name="NextWindow">
    <allDesktops>no<allDesktops>
  </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="C-A-Tab">
  <action name="NextWindow">
    <allDesktops>yes<allDesktops>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: There is no `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` but `~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml` which contains keybindings among other things. Should I edit this file?

Comment: Yes. Make a backup of the file so you can easily revert if things go wrong. Let me know how it works, then I will update the answer to reflect the actual file in Lubuntu (what I provided is for "generic" openbox).

Comment: worked like a charm! thx :)